# SQL Count Aggregate with Multiple Having Conditions

Tags: sql, count, having-clause

I am attempting to write a SQL query that only returns employees that have multiple transactions on the same date (count(TransactionDate) > 1), but the transactions occurred within different store IDs. I am attempting to use a combination of the count aggregate and having, but can't seem to return the correct values. Would a temp table be a better way to do it, or maybe a sub query? My below query is not returning accurate records. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
EmployeeID  | StoreID | TransactionDate
--------------------------------------
     1      |   1     | 2016-09-09    --should be returned
--------------------------------------
     1      |   2     | 2016-09-09    --should be returned
--------------------------------------
     1      |   3     | 2016-09-09    --should be returned
--------------------------------------
     1      |   1     | 2016-09-18    --should not be returned
--------------------------------------
     2      |   1     | 2016-09-09    --should not be returned
--------------------------------------
     2      |   1     | 2016-09-09    --should not be returned
--------------------------------------
     3      |   1     | 2016-09-09    --should not be returned
--------------------------------------
     4      |   5     | 2016-09-09    --should be returned
 --------------------------------------
     4      |   6     | 2016-09-09    --should be returned

select top 1000 EmployeeID, StoreID, TransactionDate, count(StoreID)[StoreCount], count(TransactionDate)[Transaction Count]
from myTable  
group by EmployeeID, StoreID, TransactionDate
having count(StoreID) > 1 and count(TransactionDate) > 1
order by TransactionDate desc
```

Comment: which rdbms?  sql-sever, mysql, oracle,...? It makes a difference because this is a perfect example for window functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          EmployeeId, TransactionDate
       FROM
          Table
       GROUP BY
          EmployeeId, TransactionDate
       HAVING
          COUNT(DISTINCT StoreId) > 1
    ) e
    INNER JOIN Table t
    ON e.EmployeeId = t.EmployeeId
    AND e.TransactionDate = t.TransactionDate
```

Actually window functions wouldn't be a lot of help here because the key is to COUNT(DISTINCT StoreId) Grouped by Employee & TransactionDate and COUNT(DISTINCT ) OVER () is not allowed.  So the derived table is the way to go and this syntax will work with pretty much all of the typical RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the employees:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeId
FROM myTable t
GROUP BY EmployeeId, TransactionDate
HAVING MIN(StoreId) <> MAX(StoreId);
```

This is one of the very few situations where `select distinct` is used with `group by`.  So this type of query is a rather special thing.